# stdout and stderr from bash execution to other machine?

Tags: linux, wget, stdout, stderr

Is it possible to send stderr or stdout from a linux machine to ubuntu linux machine using at best wget or other common package at worse ( hopefully not ssh access ) ?

So far i can find a way to "stream" stdout and stderr to other machine.

Answer (score 0):

```
stdbuf -oL ./mybash.sh | while IFS= read -r line ; do wget http://myaddress.com/ --post-data="$line"; done;
```

Found an answer in this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117501/in-bash-script-how-to-capture-stdout-line-by-line)